# Repeatedly execute a keyword for a fixed time without failing if keyword does not fail

Tags: python, robotframework, ping

In my current project I need to check the stability of the Ethernet connection of a rather complex embedded system. We are using Robot Framework to perform our testcases. Now I want to ping device for a fixed amout of time and wrote a test case like this.

```
Ping Device
    [Timeout]  1 hour
    FOR   ${i}  IN RANGE  9999999
      Run Keyword And Continue On Failure   Ping Host  192.168.1.100
    END
```

The test should run for 1 hour and should be failing, if at least one ping fails. Still, it shouldn't abort to see in how many cases the ping fails. Unfortunatel, the test is also failing due to the timeout, which seems to be a sane and desired behaviour from Robot Framework, that shouldn't be misused as I did.

How, can I still repeatedly execute a keyword for exactly one hour and only fail if the keyword failed at least once?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

To run a keyword for a certain amount of time you should use the [Repeat Keyword](http://robotframework.org/robotframework/latest/libraries/BuiltIn.html#Repeat%20Keyword). Mind that it will generate a lot of logs so I suggest checking [Removing and flattening keywords](http://robotframework.org/robotframework/latest/RobotFrameworkUserGuide.html#removing-and-flattening-keywords) chapter in the user guide.

Now to fail a test if one iteration has failed I would suggest using the [Run Keyword And Return Status](http://robotframework.org/robotframework/latest/libraries/BuiltIn.html#Run%20Keyword%20And%20Return%20Status) in a user keyword which would store any failure in a test variable that you could use to fail your test case overall.

Here is an example with a happy and an unhappy case that would run each keyword for 5 seconds.

```
*** Test Cases ***
Test OK
    Set Test Variable    ${OVERALL RESULT}    True
    Repeat Keyword    5 sec    Run Keyword And Store Failure   Sleep    1 sec    reason=test
    Run Keyword If    ${OVERALL RESULT} == False    Fail    over all fail
    
Test NOK
    Set Test Variable    ${OVERALL RESULT}    True
    Repeat Keyword    5 sec    Run Keyword And Store Failure   Fail    test
    Run Keyword If    ${OVERALL RESULT} == False    Fail    over all fail
    
Test With Random Failures In It
    Set Test Variable    ${OVERALL RESULT}    True
    Repeat Keyword    5 sec    Run Keyword And Store Failure   Fail Randomly
    Run Keyword If    ${OVERALL RESULT} == False    Fail    over all fail
    
*** Keyword ***
Run Keyword And Store Failure
    [arguments]    ${keyword}    @{args}
    ${status}=    Run Keyword And Return Status    ${keyword}    @{args}
    Run Keyword If    ${status} == False    Set Test Variable    ${OVERALL RESULT}    False

Fail Randomly
    ${numbers}=    Evaluate    random.sample(range(1, 200), 4)    random
    Run Keyword If    ${numbers}[0]%2 != 0    Fail     fail  randomly
    Sleep    1 sec     reason=reduce log lines
```

Comment: Many thanks for the fast reply. It will take some time to digest your answer. I'll see if I can utilize it.

Comment: @Aleph0 Let me know if you need more clarification.

Comment: No I'm fine with your answer so far. I'll see how I can use it in production.